# Understanding a function in Linux source code

Tags: c, comparison-operators

I have an assignment related to scheduling in which I need to modify Linux source code. I came across a piece of code which I don't understand.

```
static inline int entity_before(struct sched_entity *a, struct sched_entity *b) {
     return (s64)(a->vruntime - b->vruntime) < 0;
}
```

what does this line `return (s64)(a->vruntime - b->vruntime) < 0;` return? To me it seems it is returning a Boolean value like in Java, if the statement is true then it returns 1 and if it's false then it returns 0? As C language doesn't have a boolean data type.

Comment: "As C language doesn't have a boolean data type." --> For over 20 years, since C99, C has a boolean type.  Suggest using more up-to-date references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line returns `0` or `1`. The result of operator `<` is an `int` value of `1` if the condition is (logically) true, or an `int` type of value `0` if the condition holds false.

> To me it seems it is returning a Boolean value like in java, if the statement is true then it returns 1 and if its false then it returns 0?

Yes.

> as C language doesn't have a boolean data type.

is false - C language has `_Bool` data type. Still, operator `<` returns an `int`, *not* a `_Bool`.

See [cppreference comparision operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison)